# Remove row but total don't change

Tags: jquery, datatables

In my example I'm trying to delete some rows with a button (#Bt_CancTable) and I need to automatic update the page total in salary column.

If I change the number of rows displayed the total is dynamically updated, I need do the same removing the checked rows.

thank you in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Bt_CancTable').click( function() {
        $('#example').find('tr').each(function () {   
            var row = $(this);
            if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') ) {
                console.log('Deleted ROW: '+row.index());
                row.remove();
            };
        });
    }); 
        
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            targets:   0,
            className: 'dt-body-center',
            render: function (data, type, full, meta){
             return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
         }
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        footerCallback: function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                        var api = this.api(), data;

                        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                        var intVal = function ( i ) {
                            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*0.001 :
                                typeof i === 'number' ?
                                    i : 0;
                        };

                        // Total over all pages
                        total = api
                            .column( 5 )
                            .data()
                            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                            }, 0 );
                        
                        // Total over this page
                        pageTotal = api
                            .column( 5, { page: 'current'} )
                            .data()
                            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                            }, 0 );
                        
                        // Update footer
                        $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(
                            'K$ '+pageTotal +' ( '+ total +' K$ total)'
                        );
            }  
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<div id="wrapper">
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="Bt_CancTable">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i>
                                    <span>Cancella selezionati</span>
            </button>   
        </div>  
        <div>
<table id="example" class="table" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        </div>    
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you work up a JSFiddle so we can see what's happening?

Comment: I have insert all my code in snippet, you can test it with the button "Run code snippet". If you test you can see so when you delete a row with yellow button "Cancella selezionati" the total at the end of salary column don't change (I need change) but if you change the number of rows displayed with "Show XX entries" the total of salary change. 
Thankyou

Comment: I think so the problem is when I remove the row. in the
    $('#Bt_CancTable').click( function() {... if I remove a row and afther I change the number of rows to display the removed row reappears.

Comment: You're mixing apples with oranges with your current code, while your button removes the row it doesn't remove it from the DataTable model of the data! You need to have something that stores all of the data in your row (or an index if you have a unique value) and then removes the data from DataTable model of the data, then redraws the table. This might help to start with: http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the variable globally, before changing the other values.

Comment: Can you write more details I cant understand what you mean. Thankyou.

Comment: Add `var total;` just below `$(document).ready(function(){`, then set your total like this `total = 'logic_for_total'` before you delete any rows. Total will now, and always equal whatever you set it to before deleting rows, as long as you don't reset it later.

Comment: Sorry but the same I don't know what and how set "total" variable using deleted cell value